How to identify the need to VPA (after moving to ZGC)?
Problem Statement: Need to identify the right metrics to trigger vertical pod autoscaling for my deployment.
Previous Solution : Since G1GC would 'stop the world', I could use the stopping time as a factor.
Current Issue: After moving to ZGC, I have no such metrics since GC happens parallelly with my application threads
